# case when evaluation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, aggregate, lazy-evaluation

I've been working with SQLServer for many years now and always had the idea of CASE expression using lazy evaluation, which allows doing things such as check whether a string value contains a valid date before actually trying to convert it.

Today I found an scenario where this seems not true. After some simplification, this is an easy example to show it (don't try to find any sense to the calculation, just a fool example):

```
select b, sum(case when b<> 0 then a / b end)
from (
    select 1 as a, 1 as b union select 1, 0 union select 0, 1
) x group by b
```

This works fine, as I would expect.

```
select b, case when b<> 0 then sum(a / b) end
from (
    select 1 as a, 1 as b union select 1, 0 union select 0, 1
) x group by b
```

This throws an error (zero division).

Seems something related to the aggregate function, somehow the sum is evaluating before the case does, but I must be missing something and don't know what.

I'm mostly curious about this, as there are some workarounds and don't have a real problem with it.

By the way, I've test it on SQLServer 2005 and SQLServer 2008, and then on Oracle 11g, with same result always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second version, the aggregate `sum(a/b)` has to be calculated for the entire result set, because there are no per-row conditionals in it. Then each row decides whether to include that value using the `CASE` expression.